# How to update DOM with HTML returned from server after JQuery File Upload is done?

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to use Blueimp JQuery File Upload to upload an image to my server. The server then returns a HTML `<img>` tag which I want to append to my DOM to show the user what image was uploaded. They can then do further things like crop it using JCrop or whatever.

I am able to upload the image to the server just fine. And the server returns this "`<img src="/path/to/temporary/image.jpg" />`"

I want to append this HTML code to a div but I'm not able to get this part working.

HTML:

```
<!-- file input -->
<input id="ProfileImage" type="file" name="ProfileImage" />
<!-- upload progress bar --->
<div id="progress" class="progress">
     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
</div>
<!-- div to which I want to append the server's html response -->
<div id="files" class="files"></div>
```

JQuery File Upload:

```
        $('#ProfileImage').fileupload({
            url: '/path/to/server',
            autoUpload: true,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
            maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5 MB
            done: function (e, data) {
                $('#files').append(data); // This is obviously not working!
            },
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
            }
        });
```

I just want to end up with my page HTML looking like this at the end of the upload:

```
<...>
<!-- image HTML inserted into the div -->
<div id="files" class="files"><img src="path/to/image" /></div>
```

If I use `alert(data)` to see what comes back I just get a dialog showing `[object Object]`. But if I look in the console in Firebug and click on the Response tab in the Post event that submitted the image, it shows `<img src="userfiles/newimage.jpg" />` as the output from the server.

Comment: Is the correct HTML being returned? (use an alert to show this)

Comment: What do you get in the console when you add `console.log(data)` to your `done` handler?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674999/jquery-fileupload-doesnt-trigger-done possible duplicate of this question.

Comment: @rorymcrossan if I use alert(data) to see what comes back I just get a dialog showing `[object Object]`. But if I look in the console in Firebug and click on the Response tab it shows `<img src="userfiles/newimage.jpg" />` as the output from the server.

Comment: @volumeone yeah, don't ever use `alert` for debugging - it's useless. Can you do `console.log(data)` and see what that is. You're returning an object of some type which is why the append isn't working - that expects a string DOMElement or jQuery object.

Comment: @volumeone just check the DOC, sounds like it should be `data.result`

Comment: If you view the HTML on the page, does it show the html appended correctly or is it missing?

Comment: @A.Wolff aha! it was indeed that. How am I supposed to know this / find this out myself in future? Where should I be looking to know what is contained in `data` ?

Comment: @volumeone https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#user-content-done

Comment: @volumeone As a general advice (see Rory's comment), use `console.log()` (or console.dir()) and check all properties of object. This is usually the fastest way to check an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this should be:

```
$('#files').append(data.result);
```

Comment: Yup, as @A. Wolf said

Comment: I thought I should delete it because it started in the wrong direction. I'm sorry if this isn't the right way to do it, should I delete this one instead and edit that one then?

Comment: He said it in the comments and I didn't see it. I'll delete my answer if he posts is. This question is still quite a duplicate of a few other I found.

Comment: @JoãoMiguelBrandão No keep your answer, you obviously just checked the DOC too ;)

Comment: What is the DOC? How should one know where to look for the correct data?

Comment: @volumeone DOC for documentation. At your credit, this plugin documentation isn't the best/most descriptive i have seen

Comment: Have to agree to that @A.Wolff When I wanted to do file upload, I used standard jQuery / AJAX and it worked quite seamlessly, you don't need a plugin to do this task.

Comment: @JoãoMiguelBrandão IIRC this plugin is great to handle older browsers (IE8?) multiple files upload