# File Upload Issue in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Once I upload a file through input type, it then gets disabled, can't upload another file until the page is refreshed. I don't want to upload multiple files at once, but one after the other. Then click on submit.

**My code:**

```
<i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i>
<span>
    <input type="file" id="video-dancing" name="postVideo" accept="video/*">
</span>
```

Comment: What is Question?

Comment: So then you have to create another upload control dynamically. You cannot append files again and again.

Comment: Once i click on input type, i can't click it again to select another file, until the page is refreshed.

Comment: There has an answer in your question !!!

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674999/jquery-fileupload-doesnt-trigger-done) .It may helps you

Answer (score 0):

https://daveismyname.com/upload-multiple-files-with-a-single-input-with-html-5-and-php-bp

hope this would help your problem .

Answer (score 0):

Once the first upload is complete, simply add code to refresh the page.

Comment: is there anyother option where i dont have to refresh the page??

Comment: Then use multiple as people have suggested, I think using multiple you can select one file at a time and then finally hit submit.

Answer (score -1):

use attribute multiple to select multiple files.

```
<input type="file" id="video-dancing" name="postVideo" accept="video/*" multiple >
```

Comment: it should multiple="multiple"

Comment: @Ashraful Islam Tushar i don't want to upload multiple files at once, sir

Comment: @mahendrapratapjewaria : did you ever tried only multiple ? you should study first about something, then try to teach someone. for your reference  got to - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp

Comment: @AshrafulIslamTushar read the question again. He Said **I don't want to upload multiple files at once**

Comment: It doesn't look like OP wanted a multi file upload.

Comment: @mahendrapratapjewaria : yes they both work i know, then you shouldn't say that "it should be".

Comment: @abizz is there any particular reason why you don't want the page to refresh?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile: that was something the client asked for!